# Multiple INTOs in procedure query

Tags: mysql, procedure

Is it possible to add multiple INTOs into one query in a procedure to write the values into variables. I tried to do the followng, which does not work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE slave (IN lat double, IN lon double, OUT var_procId BIGINT, OUT lati BIGINT)
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO var_procId, Locations.latitude into lati  FROM Locations WHERE latitude=lat AND longitude=lon LIMIT 1;
END;
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is of limited use

Answer (score 1):

just use it in the order you want to use, like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE slave (IN lat double, IN lon double, OUT var_procId BIGINT, OUT lati BIGINT)
BEGIN
    SELECT id, Locations.latitude into  var_procId, lati  FROM Locations WHERE latitude=lat AND longitude=lon LIMIT 1;
END;
```